# Pandas Preprocessing: Labelling time series data using 2 other files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, dask

I am trying to categorise time series data using categories from another file.
I have uploaded pictures of the three files, the photos are linked below.

This has been the bane of my life for the past couple of days.

I am trying to create a labeled dataset for behavior recognition. I have 2 CVS files to help me label my CSV file.

### 1. Data

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bm8F.png) is what the data frame I need to label looks like. Data was collected 40 times a second, for months. I also have all this data for different individuals, so I have split them into each individual and then into files with 1000000 rows. The CSV file originally had separate columns for date, hour, second, decimal second but I made this into one timestamp, in the hope that I could use this as an index and then do something like:

```
df['Label'].iloc[starttime:endtime] = "Grooming"
```

I was thinking about using unix timestamps as an index also. The dtype of timestamp is object.

### Files to use in labeling

#### 2.  Behavioural States

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O31n2.png) is what the file with each label looks like. So we can see grooming starts at 11:26:48 and ends at 11:28:32. However, there are large gaps in the data from when the animal was not being observed. So we cannot always take the end time from below. This is where our final dataframe comes in.

### 3. Start and end times of observations.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqBNR.png) is our final dataframe. We have the start and end times of each focal observation, giving us the boundaries for our looping.

### What I have tried.

I initially thought that having nested for loops would be the way to go. Making a copy of the timestamp data from the file that needs labelling, making a labels column then setting it to 0.

I was then going to get the start and end times from file 3, then while the time in file 2 is between those times, for each activty in file 2, set the label column of my series.

I was going to use the times like an index as shown above, however since file 1 is 40hz, I cannot just append some zeros onto my timestamps from files 2 and 3 as there may not be a reading for the start of each second. I know [pandas has a between time function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html), however this would require me to split my data into each day and I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many weeks of working on this problem, I have managed to come up with a solution. This solution, however, only uses pandas and therefore, I shall run it on lots of smaller files then combine them at the end.

### Loading up the data

First I load up the data:

```
path = '/media/peter/ElementsSE/Labelling3/Small/prepared_collar3_0.csv'
times = pd.read_csv(path)

path = '/media/peter/Elements SE/Labelling3/Small/3labels.csv'
labels = pd.read_csv(path)

path = '/media/peter/ElementsSE/Labelling3/Small/3TimesForLabels.csv'
label_times = pd.read_csv(path)
```

### Preperation

After loading up the data, I then make timestamps for each one:

```
labels['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(labels['Date(M/DD/YY)'])
labels['Timestamp'] = labels.apply(lambda row: str(row['Date'].date()) + ' ' + str(row['Time']),axis=1) 
#Casting from string to timestamp
labels['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(labels['Timestamp'])

label_times['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(label_times['Date(M/DD/YY)'])
label_times['Timestamp'] = label_times.apply(lambda row: str(row['Date'].date()) + ' ' + str(row['Time']),axis=1) 
#Casting from string to timestamp
label_times['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(label_times['Timestamp'])
```

### Making our new column that contains the labels

Make sure to set the category column of my dataset to None, so I can see how much of the data gets labeled.

```
times['behav'] = None
times.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(times.Timestamp)
times.head()
```

### Looping Through the files

After this we then need to loop through the 3 files and label them:

```
#Iterating though labeltimes to get the right start and end times
for i in range(len(label_times)-1):
    date = label_times.loc[i,'Date']
    focal_start_time = label_times.loc[i,'Timestamp']
    focal_end_time = label_times.loc[i+1,'Timestamp']


    #Now we iterate though the labels
    day_labels = labels.loc[labels.Date == date].reset_index()
    for j in range(len(day_labels)-1):
        time = day_labels.loc[j,'Timestamp']
        next_time = day_labels.loc[j+1,'Timestamp']
        behav = day_labels.loc[j,'Focal Behavioral States']

        if(time.date() == focal_start_time.date()):

            #We have data of the same date 
            if(time.time() <= focal_end_time.time()):
                if(time.time() >= focal_start_time.time()):

                    #Our start time is in the time range, now we need to check the end time
                    if(next_time.time() <= focal_end_time.time()):
                        if(next_time.time() >= focal_start_time.time()):
                            times.behav.loc[(times.Timestamp >= time) & (times.Timestamp <= next_time)] = behav
```

Times is now a labeled dataset. You may find it useful to see how much of your data is labeled with what, I did this using:

```
times.behav.value_counts()
```

Sorry that this is very specific to my problem, hopefully, this will help someone else on a similar problem and if they are like me, save them a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a script for this type of problem when I was labelling 112,00 rows of neural time series data and had the start and finish times of each event.

## **1. Load your data into the script**

Load in (1) Your time series data, (2) Your event markings data, and (3) The sample rate of your time series data (i.e. whether you recorded in deci-seconds, seconds etc).

```
# Your time series data file name
data_file_name = 'data_time_series.csv'

# Your time series data csv
data = pd.read_csv(data_file_name, encoding='utf-8', skiprows=0)

# Your events data
events = pd.read_csv("event_durations.csv", encoding='utf-8', skiprows=1)

sample_rate = 0.1  #Deci-seconds
```

## **2. Break the start-finish times into a column of seconds/deci-seconds**

This function simply takes the time durations from your event markings dataframe and turns it into a column of seconds/deci-seconds (depending on the sample rate you entered in step 1).

```
def addRange (events):
    global events_split 
    events_split = pd.DataFrame()
    events = np.array(events)
    row = 0
    for _row in events:
        x = round(events[row,0],1) # Start time
        y = round(events[row,1],1) # End time
        events_split = events_split.append(pd.DataFrame([x]))
        while x < y:
            x = round((x + sample_rate),1)
            events_split = events_split.append(pd.DataFrame([x]))
        row = row + 1
    return events_split

addRange(events)
```

## **3. Convert that list into a column of 1s and 0s**

For this function, we need to first create an iterable variable containing the “time” column of your time series data:

`data_time_col = pd.DataFrame([data.iloc[:,0]]) data_time_col = data_time_col.T`

The function below then uses this variable, along with the newly broken down event markings data, to create a column of 1s and 0s that exactly matches the rows on your time series data.

```
def addEvents(data_time_col):
    global labels_01_df
    labels_01_df = pd.DataFrame() 
    for i in data_time_col.values:
        if i in events_split.values:
            labels_01_df = labels_01_df.append([1], ignore_index=True)
        else:
            labels_01_df = labels_01_df.append([0], ignore_index=True)
    return labels_01_df

addEvents(data_time_col)
```

## **4. Write the column of 1s and 0s into a “labels” column in the data file**

Lastly, we need to insert your list of 0s and 1s into your time series dataframe and export it to csv. (The new column will be inserted in index [0] and push the other columns along). The new, labelled file will appear in your directory with the same name as the original file but with “LABELLED” at the end.

```
data.insert(loc=0, column="labels", value=labels_01_df)
data.to_csv(data_file_name + " - LABELLED.csv", index=False)
```

I hope that's helpful. There is some further information around this process here as well: https://medium.com/@lucy.m.rothwell/labelling-time-series-data-in-python-af62325e8f60